# Eclipse on Ubuntu gives "Update LCD" error when setting up a run configuration with a File System working directory

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

When configuring a new run on Eclipse, and selecting a working directory from "Other" -> "File System", the whole 'Run Configurations' box becomes unusable and I cannot access any more settings for that launch configuration or any other ones that was already there. This only happens if at least one of the run configurations is set up to use another folder from "Other" instead of the default. It has always worked on my other machines running Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 but it just happened on the new one with 13.04. I could not get it to work, I tried different versions of Eclipse, different versions of the Java. Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. Perhaps its throw because you have installed on eclipse run Jetty plugin, you have one debug configuration realtive to close project.

To solve it, you have to open the project before open run configurations.